# c#:converting address to longitude and latitude

Tags: c#, google-maps

i was trying to convert address into longitude and latitude using this code using geocoding api

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IGeocoder geocoder = new GoogleGeocoder() {  };
    Address[] addresses = geocoder.Geocode("#65/1 bangalore").ToArray();
    foreach (Address adrs in addresses)
    {
        Response.Write("address:"+adrs);
    }
}
```

the answer i got was the more detailed address not the longitude and latitude .for example for this code i got

```
address:Hari Om Trust Tapovana, 1, Bangalore, Karnataka 562123, India
```

someone please tell me what modification i have to do so that i could get longitude and latitude?

the code for googlegeocoder is

```
 #region Assembly Geocoding.dll, v3.1.0.0
    // C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\learn1\Bin\Geocoding.dll
    #endregion

    using Geocoding;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace Geocoding.Google
    {
        public class GoogleGeocoder : IGeocoder, IAsyncGeocoder
        {
            public GoogleGeocoder();

            public string ApiKey { get; set; }
            public Bounds BoundsBias { get; set; }
            public BusinessKey BusinessKey { get; set; }
            public string Language { get; set; }
            public WebProxy Proxy { get; set; }
            public string RegionBias { get; set; }
            public string ServiceUrl { get; }

            public IEnumerable<GoogleAddress> Geocode(string address);
            public Task<IEnumerable<GoogleAddress>> GeocodeAsync(string address);
            public Task<IEnumerable<GoogleAddress>> GeocodeAsync(string address, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
            public IEnumerable<GoogleAddress> ReverseGeocode(Location location);
            public IEnumerable<GoogleAddress> ReverseGeocode(double latitude, double longitude);
            public Task<IEnumerable<GoogleAddress>> ReverseGeocodeAsync(double latitude, double longitude);
            public Task<IEnumerable<GoogleAddress>> ReverseGeocodeAsync(double latitude, double longitude, CancellationToken cancellationToken);

            protected class RequestState
            {
                public readonly CancellationToken? cancellationToken;
                public readonly HttpWebRequest request;

                public RequestState(HttpWebRequest request, CancellationToken? cancellationToken);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post the code of the GoogleGeocoder class.

Comment: "#65/1 bangalore", is that supposed to be an actual address ?

Comment: yea.you can give any address you want that contain real place name.

Comment: Where is GoogleGeocoder coming from. URL please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahh... quite simple in Fact:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IGeocoder geocoder = new GoogleGeocoder() {  };
    Address[] addresses = geocoder.Geocode("#65/1 bangalore").ToArray();
    foreach (Address adrs in addresses)
    {
        Response.Write("address:"+adrs.Coordinates);
    }
}
```

Cheers

EDIT: The reason you're only seeing a street address is because of Address.ToString() being called by default in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to :
Google has a geocoding API which seems to work pretty well for most of the locations that they have Google Maps data for.

http://googlemapsapi.blogspot.com/2006/06/geocoding-at-last.html

They provide online geocoding (via JavaScript):

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#Geocoding

Or backend geocoding (via an HTTP request):

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#Geocoding_Direct

The data is usually the same used by Google Maps itself. (note that there are some exceptions to this, such as the UK or Israel, where the data is from a different source and of slightly reduced quality)

Answer (score 0):

Here is good and simple example:

[Adress to Lat- long generation](http://coderskey.blogspot.in/2015/03/how-to-get-lat-long-from-address-in-c.html)

Thanks